# Elevator idle power where does it go to

Tags: energy

We have a hydraulic elevator in our 4-storey building which appears to be using quite a lot of energy even at night when it is not in use. I measured an average of 3 kWh of energy over a 10-hour time period which means the elevator is using about 300 W while idle.

From an internet search this number appears typical for hydraulic elevators, however, I am curious, where does all this energy go to? It is a fairly large expense.

Comment: ask the manufacturer

Comment: the drop protection system is still active ... it probably uses power to keep it disengaged

Comment: This is a hydraulic elevator which automatically goes to the bottom floor when not in use for a few minutes. In this case the drop protection system should not be needed.

Comment: Energy tends to go to heat.  Controls are waiting for someone to call an elevator.  There are probably ways to make things more efficient but would it be worth the cost?

Comment: Get a clamp on multimeter and start measuring things. Shouldn't be too hard to figure it out.

At 300W, something is going to be getting hot.

Answer (score -1):

- Control panel maybe 100 W.
- Lights maybe 100 W.
- Solenoids would normally all be off when stationary but perhaps not.

Comment: Ligths are off when it's idle.